# c# Make TcpServer Block

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am using C# to make a server and client. I want it to be blocking for the purpose of what I am doing. When I use NetworkStream.read(), it blocks and I like it like that. The problem is that when I use NetworkStream.ReadByte(), it DOESN'T block. It instead returns -1 when there is no incoming byte. How can I make NetworkStream.ReadByte() to block like NetworkStream.read()?

I've tried to enclose NetworkStream.ReadByte() in NetworkStream.DataAvailable but that didn't work either. I just wantNetworkStream.ReadByte() to block. Any ideas?

Comment: You got an answer that IMHO is the best given your request. But: I think you should rethink _both_ the decision to use a blocking paradigm, and especially the decision to try to read one byte at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1];
stream.Read(buf, 0, 1);
```

Edit: Of course if you're doing this a lot don't allocate the new buffer each time, store it as a field on the object & allocate it in the constructor.

Comment: I am trying to use NetworkStream.ReadByte() for efficient because it returns a byte. There is no way to fix NetworkStream.ReadByte()  and make it block?

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, you shouldn't be reading the stream one block at a time :) "as efficiently as possible" - there should be no performance difference between Read() and ReadByte(), provided you allocate the buffer only once.

Comment: Thanks. I restarted my computer and now, it blocks. I still decided to go with your method. 
What I am doing is actually trying to stream video from my camera to another computer using Unity3D. Right now, it looks like an image-slide show being displayed on a vintage calculator :)  I am sending 307200 bytes through network and it takes about 3-5 minutes to arrive. lol

Answer (score 2):

`ReadByte` blocks. It only returns -1 at the end of the stream. You must be misinterpreting what you are seeing. Replace `ReadByte` with the workaround suggested by nevelis and you'll see no difference in behavior.

Comment: You are correct. After I restarted my computer, it began to block. That's weird. I will give nevelis credit for proving code answer. Thanks. I used his answer instead of ReadByte.

Comment: I thought it should have been blocking... :D this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find anything clear on this in the MSDN documentation, but now that we have the open source CoreFX we can look at the implementation:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1bd332f2e5f559c2eab276acb0d9e4256085ec2f/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1bd332f2e5f559c2eab276acb0d9e4256085ec2f/src/System.IO/src/System/IO/Stream.cs

NetworkStream overrides Read to call to Socket.Receive, which is blocking, but does not override ReadByte. Stream.ReadByte just calls to Read, so NetworkStream.ReadBytes will call into the blocking NetworkStream.Read.